# Python For Vector

Tags: python, for-loop, vector

```
n = int(input("Enter how many numbers will be stored : "))
vet1 = [n]
vet2 = [n]

print("Enter the numbers to be stored")
for i in range(n):
    vet1 = int(input(f"number {i}: "))
for i in range(n):
    if (vet1%2 == 0):
        vet2 = vet1 + 1
        print(f"\nThe number entered was {vet1}\nYour successor is {vet2}\n")
    else:
        vet2 = vet1 - 1
        print(f"\nThe number entered was {vet1}\nYour predecessor is {vet2}\n")
```

I want to achieve this result

The number entered was 1
Its predecessor is 0

The number entered was 2
His successor is 3

The number entered was 3
Its predecessor is 2

but I can't store the numbers in the vector
Please, help.

Comment: Just delete the second `for` statement.  That's all you have to do.

Comment: Python's lists are not vectors, they're dynamic - they don't have a set size as you seem to think in lines 2 & 3! You're also overwriting them. Use the [`.append(vet1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method to add numbers to your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code simply achieved the desired output. The mistake is the first loop which can be a hurdle, basically you don't need another loop with same length. Simply remove this loop.

```
for i in range(n):#Line 5
```

and copy input `vet1 = int(input(f"number {i}: "))`line and paste in an other loop

```
n = int(input("Enter how many numbers will be stored : "))
vet1 = [n]
vet2 = [n]

print("Enter the numbers to be stored")

   
for i in range(n):
    vet1 = int(input(f"number {i}: "))
    if (vet1%2 == 0):
        vet2 = vet1 + 1
        print(f"\nThe number entered was {vet1}\nYour successor is {vet2}\n")
    else:
        vet2 = vet1 - 1
        print(f"\nThe number entered was {vet1}\nYour predecessor is {vet2}\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

As the above comments said you have to append the value in order to store the values.

```
n = int(input("Enter how many numbers will be stored : "))
vet = []

print("Enter the numbers to be stored")
for i in range(n):
    vet1 = int(input(f"number {i}: "))
    vet.append(vet1)
for i in vet:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        vet2 = i + 1
        print(f"\nThe number entered was {i}\nYour successor is {vet2}\n")
    else:
        vet2 = i - 1
        print(f"\nThe number entered was {i}\nYour predecessor is {vet2}\n")
```